# Make single request to database in ASP NET 3.1 MVC, Vertical slice architecture command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP NET 3.1 MVC application i am using vertical slice architecture so for example my UpdateRecordCommand.cs looks like this:

```
public static class UpdateRecordCommand
{
    public class Request : IRequest<Response>
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public RecordDTO Record {get; set;}
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public RecordDTO Record {get; set;}
    }

    public class Validator: IAbstractValidator<Request>
    {
        private readonly IRecordRepository _repository;
        public Validator(IRecordRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            RuleFor(x => x)
                .CustomAsync(ProperRecordStatus);
        }

        private async Task ProperRecordStatus(Request request, CustomContext customContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var dbRecord = await _repository.GetRecordById(request.Id, cancellationToken)
            
            if(dbRecord == null)
            {
                customContext.AddFailure("Record Id", Errors.RecordNotExists);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Request, Response>
    {
        private readonly IRecordRepository _repository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public Handler(IRecordRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _mapper = mapper
        }

        public async Task<Response> Handle(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var record = _mapper.Map<Record>(request.Record);
            var dbRecord = await _repository.GetRecordById(request.Id, cancellationToken);
            dbRecord.Update(record);
            await _repository.UpdateRecord(dbRecord, cancellationToken);

            return new Response {Record = _mapper.Map<RecordDTO>(dbRecord)};
        }
    }
}
```

Currently in handler and validator i am making two request to database retrieving the same object. I was wondering if its possible to make single call to database so i can work on the same object in validator and handler removing this way one extra reqeust to database. If so whats the best way to do it?

Comment: _"vertical slice architecture"_ - you're saying this as if it makes clear what your code looks like, but it doesn't. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The question of how long, under what circumstances, in which context a loaded entity remains valid (could be cached instead of retrieved again) heavily depends on your architecture and usage patterns. If caching is a valid option some times, consider to implement it as part of your repository or as a wrapper around your actual repository implementation.

Comment: Make it a habit to do the leanest possible queries in the validator. Don't fetch an entire object only to check if it exists. Run a query with `Any`. If your architecture prevents doing that, fix the architecture (a repository layer on top of EF's repositories (DbSets) is usually not helpful at all). Don't introduce state dependencies between validation and handling.